# ¿Cómo obtengo el elemento de una tupla por su índice?

Tags: haskell

Usando las listas puedo obtener el elemento del índice `X` usando el operador `!!`.

Por ejemplo:

```
Prelude> let lista = [2,4..20]
Prelude> lista
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
Prelude> lista !! 0
2
Prelude> lista !! 5
12
```

Ahora que estoy conociendo las tuplas en Haskell, si trato de acceder de la misma forma a un elemento por su índice, me sale error:

```
Prelude> let tupla = (1, "Hola", 'Z')
Prelude> tupla
(1,"Hola",'Z')
Prelude> tupla !! 1

<interactive>:9:1:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]'
                with actual type `(Integer, [Char], Char)'
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `tupla'
    In the expression: tupla !! 1
    In an equation for `it': it = tupla !! 1
```

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de acceder a los elementos de las tuplas por su índice?

Comment: Me parece que no se puede, navegando por internet fue fácil encontrar alguna respuesta o salida a esto, aquí un link de ayuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558278/how-to-get-nth-element-from-a-10-tuple-in-haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las tuplas no son estructuras de datos que se indexen por un entero.

Para acceder a los elementos de un par, puedes hacer uso de las funciones `fst` y `snd`. Si quieres acceder, por ejemplo, al tercer elemento de la tupla puedes usar pattern matching:

```
thrd:: (a,b,c) -> c
thrd (_,_,c) = c
```

O también puedes usar el `select` del [tuple package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple).

Sin embargo, no es recomendado el uso de tuplas muy grandes. Tuplas muy grandes indican, por lo general, que se debería usar otro tipo.

Comment: Interesante lo del pattern matching, aunque todavía no llego a ese tema :P

Answer (score 2):

Para añadir a la respuesta de Nicolocodev, algo que cabe señalar es la siguiente importante diferencia entre las listas y las tuplas en Haskell (y en los lenguajes con tipos estáticos, generalmente):

- En una lista, los elementos todos son de un solo tipo;
- En una tupla, el tipo de cada elemento es independiente del tipo de cualquier otro.

Esto tiene consecuencias importantes para tu pregunta.  Miremos el tipo de la función que extrae un elemento de una lista:

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

Podemos ver que la variable de tipo `a` aparece dos veces en el tipo de la función:

1. Como el tipo de los elementos de la lista en `[a]`;
2. Como el tipo del resultado de la función.

Pero ahora tratemos de imaginarnos: ¿cuál sería el tipo de la función que obtiene el elemento de una tupla por su índice?  Podemos empezar por esbozar el tipo, usando `_tupla` y `_elemento` como blancos para los tipos que trataremos de rellenar:

```
elementoDeTupla :: _tupla -> Int -> _elemento
```

El primer problema que nos enfrentamos es que no hay ningún tipo en Haskell básico que incluya entre sus valores las tuplas de todos los tamaños.  Quiérase decir, las tuplas de dos, tres, cuatro o etc. elementos son diferentes tipos, así que no podemos escribir una función que acepte tuplas de cualquier tamaño como argumento.  Para las tuplas de cada tamaño nos hace falta una función aparte:

```
elementoDeTupla2 :: (a, b)       -> Int -> _elemento
elementoDeTupla3 :: (a, b, c)    -> Int -> _elemento
elementoDeTupla4 :: (a, b, c, d) -> Int -> _elemento
```

Y ahora el segundo problema: ¿con qué tipo rellenamos los blancos que marqué con `_elemento`?  La dificultad es que dependiendo del índice que se nos de como argumento, el tipo del valor en ese elemento de la tupla es diferente.  Así que, de nuevo, no podemos escribir tal función literalmente; nos hace falta hacer algún cambio al problema.  Podríamos por ejemplo hacer lo siguiente, introduciendo tipos de suma ("sum types") que se encargan de representar el hecho de que el resultado es una suma de casos con tipos heterogéneos:

```
data Sum2 a b     = Sum2_0 a | Sum2_1 b
data Sum3 a b c   = Sum3_0 a | Sum3_1 b | Sum3_2 c
data Sum4 a b c d = Sum4_0 a | Sum4_1 b | Sum4_2 c | Sum4_3 d

elementoDeTupla2 :: (a, b)       -> Int -> Sum2 a b 
elementoDeTupla3 :: (a, b, c)    -> Int -> Sum3 a b c
elementoDeTupla4 :: (a, b, c, d) -> Int -> Sum4 a b c d
```

O podríamos requerir que todos los elementos de las tuplas sean del mismo tipo:

```
elementoDeTupla2 :: (a, a)       -> Int -> a 
elementoDeTupla3 :: (a, a, a)    -> Int -> a
elementoDeTupla4 :: (a, a, a, a) -> Int -> a
```

Ahora nuestras funciones no funcionan con todas las tuplas—sólo con aquellas cuyos elementos son de tipo homogéneo.  Pero al hacer esto hemos eliminado la mitad de la diferencia entre las tuplas y las listas—la única diferencia que queda es que las listas de diferentes largos son sin embargo valores del mismo tipo.  Recordemos que este fue el motivo por el cual introducimos `elementoDeTupla2`, `elementoDeTupla3` y `elementoDeTupla4` como funciones aparte; así que ahora, para eliminar la duplicación, terminamos donde empezamos, usando listas:

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

Y esto nos lleva a la respuesta a tu pregunta: si te hace falta obtener elementos por índice, esto indica que te hace falta usar listas, no tuplas.  (Aunque en realidad usualmente sería mejor en ese caso usar `Vector`, que permite acceso por índice en tiempo constante.)